# Visual Source Safe Add-In Missing on Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-sourcesafe

[image: Visual Studio Tools > Options Dialog]

We have a source safe server in LAN. I want to connect VSS but I cannot see "Visual Source Safe" entry in this Visual Studio 2010 dialog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install the Visual Sourcesafe 2005 client